# Calculating sum of area of selected features using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, statistics

In ArcMap, How do I write an expression that will calculate the sum of the area in square miles of features whose attribute is equal to "PRO1E"?

Answer (score 6):

Add a new field to the table called **Area** with type Double.

[image]

Right click on the field and go to Calculate Geometry.

[image]

Choose Area as the property and square miles as the units.

[image]

Do a select by attributes to only select the "PRO1E" records.

[image]

Show only the Selected Records and right click the **Area** field and go to Statistics.

[image]

Makes sure the field says **Area** and look at the sum.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated the name of your field - let's call it X

- Open the table in ArcMap
- Use Select By Attributes to select features where X = 'PRO1E'
- Right-click on the X field and choose Summarize
- Ensure that section 1 lists your field X
- In section 2 of the dialog, specify the Sum of the Area field
- Ensure the "Summarize on se lected records only" checkbox is ticked

[image]

The resulting table will show the sum of the areas of the selected features.